# Webscraper not giving the right results with bs4

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to scrape the live billionaire networth table here > https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/

This is my code so far. All I get is [] as result on the python shell.

Something has to be wrong with the "findAll", I don't think I'm using the correct tag lines.

Tried to use just "find"

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

#Open page and grab html
my_url = ('https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/')
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#HTML Parser.
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

table = []

#Find table.
ele_table = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'dvz-content'})

print(ele_table)
```

I'm expecting for the table to be printed out so I can get it into a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Data is dynamically loaded. You can pull from script tag provided you supply the right headers. Regex out the required info and parse with json library. Hand this off to pandas to write to csv

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, re, json
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'if-none-match': 'W/^\\^5dbb59e6-91b10^\\^',
    'if-modified-since': 'Thu, 31 Oct 2019 22:02:14 GMT' # this may be safeguard for caching. Consider if add dynamically.
}

p = re.compile(r'window.top500 = (.*);')
r = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/', headers = headers)
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False)
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!